# Connecting standalone UCMA application to SIP trunk provider

Tags: c#, sip, ucma

I am trying to make an outbound call from a standalone UCMA application to a SIP provider (Gamma) which authenticates based on connecting IP address. Here is the code with which I am trying to achieve this (lifted straight from Michael Greenlee (http://blog.greenl.ee/2012/06/15/outbound-calls-ucma-lync-server/):

```cs
ApplicationEndpointSettings endpointSettings =
    new ApplicationEndpointSettings("sip:02037571***@80.229.80.***"); // My Ext. IP

...

CallEstablishOptions options = new CallEstablishOptions();
options.ConnectionContext = new ConnectionContext("88.215.61.***", 5060); // Gamma Ext. IP

Conversation conv = new Conversation(_endpoint);

AudioVideoCall avcall = new AudioVideoCall(conv);

avcall.BeginEstablish("sip:07709411***@88.215.61.***", options,
    ar2 =>
    {
        try
        {
            avcall.EndEstablish(ar2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    },
    null);
```

The attempt to dial fails with Gamma returning a 403 Forbidden-Source Endpoint Lookup Failed.

I have compared wireshark traces with this failed attempt, and that of a hardware PBX which can dial out successfully.

Working hardware PBX:

```
    From: "02037571***"<sip:02037571***@80.229.80.***>;tag=39E432463135364100006C30
        SIP Display info: "02037571***"
        SIP from address: sip:02037571040@80.229.80.***
            SIP from address User Part: 02037571***
            SIP from address Host Part: 80.229.80.***
        SIP from tag: 39E432463135364100006C30
    To: <sip:07709411420@88.215.61.***:5060>
        SIP to address: sip:07709411420@88.215.61.***:5060
            SIP to address User Part: 07709411***
            SIP to address Host Part: 88.215.61.***
            SIP to address Host Port: 5060
    Contact: <sip:02037571040@80.229.80.***:5060>
        Contact URI: sip:02037571040@80.229.80.***:5060
            Contact URI User Part: 02037571***
            Contact URI Host Part: 80.229.80.***
            Contact URI Host Port: 5060
```

Failing UCMA Application:

```
        FROM: ""<sip:02037571***@80.229.80.***>;epid=C18B8F5C05;tag=be8d09ca4
        SIP Display info: ""
        SIP from address: sip:02037571***@80.229.80.***
            SIP from address User Part: 02037571***
            SIP from address Host Part: 80.229.80.***
        SIP from tag: be8d09ca4
    TO: <sip:07709411420@88.215.61.***:5060>
        SIP to address: sip:07709411420@88.215.61.***:5060
            SIP to address User Part: 07709411***
            SIP to address Host Part: 88.215.61.***
            SIP to address Host Port: 5060
    CONTACT: <sip:ADRIANHAND49F2.UnifyBusiness.local:5060;transport=Tcp;maddr=172.32.42.62;ms-opaque=260fcc58fdb93b58>;automata;actor="attendant";text;audio;video;image
        Contact URI: sip:ADRIANHAND49F2.UnifyBusiness.local:5060;transport=Tcp;maddr=172.32.42.62;ms-opaque=260fcc58fdb93b58
            Contact URI Host Part: ADRIANHAND49F2.UnifyBusiness.local
            Contact URI Host Port: 5060
            Contact URI parameter: transport=Tcp
            Contact URI parameter: maddr=172.32.42.62
            Contact URI parameter: ms-opaque=260fcc58fdb93b58
```

As you can see, the FROM and TO portions are largely similar, but the CONTACT portion contains the particulars of my machine and domain rather than those I specified as the Application Endpoint, as well as the LAN IP of my machine (maddr=172.32.42.62).

If I debug and inspect _endpoint, the EndpointUri property contains the ADRIANHAND49F2.UnifyBusiness.local string which I believe is the reason Gamma is rejecting my attempt to make a call. This property is readonly so I am a little bit stuck - can anybody help me connect to my SIP provider, please? All thoughts gratefully received, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The contact address is coming from the [ServerPlatformSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh382649.aspx) parameters (localhost / port).

If you change the localhost parameter to a dotted address (or name that makes more sense to you), that should work for you, I hope.

What I don't know is how to set a user of the contact URI, but I'm not sure that matters.